# How to grasp in romantic relationship the difference of "to be identified with" and "do the identifying"?

Tags: love, relations

I've been doing close reading for my bachelor thesis and I struggle with concept regarding love as union.
To set a little bit of context:
I concentrate specifically on creation and the problematic nature of *we* as some close unity between two lovers. The author (N. Delaney) firstly discuss how I want my lover to regard my interests, and finally how I want to see myself standing in relation to his/hers. Where, for me, the problematic part begins. In creation of *we* it is important to take myself as a significant contributor to the well-being of the significant other. (Meant not in extreme way but let us say just as in a supporting role.) But there is a problem called "free-riding" - where:

> your lover's role in your development far exceeds your perceived role in hers,

which this author grasps as generally unsatisfying.

He is asking:

> Why pursuit of romantic ideal doesn't stop short of genuinely taking the other's needs and interests unto yourself....**Why is it so important to do the identifying rather than merely to be identified with?**

And I am not sure how to understand the second part of the question. What is the difference between doing the identifying and being identified with?

Is "doing the identifying" meant like me taking the interest and needs of the other? If yes, than what the "being identified with" does mean?

Maybe it is problem of language barrier as I am not English native speaker. But I have been struggling with this specificity for a long time.

Comment: it could just be how, if my partner likes collecting toy trains, i should want to see them collect more toy trains, not just collect toy trains myself

Comment: so yeah i guess "identifying" refers to "needs" here.